# Perl regrex: exlude pattern from matching

Tags: regex, perl

I have `/home/user/abc/def/mng` and I'd like to replace `/home/user` or I had do a check before that if the string contain $HOME then exclude $HOME or `/home/user` from matching and process something on pattern `/abc/def/mng`.

How to exlucde?

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Because I'd be suggesting `File::Spec` and just doing logical tests.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood well your question, you need something like that:

```
my $newstring = $oldstring =~ s/(\/home\/user)|(\$HOME)//gr;
```

Have a look here: http://tpcg.io/xukvqn

Answer (score 1):

This isn't particularly clever but it does what I think you are asking:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $variable = '/home/jtym/abc/def/mng';
my $home_if_exists;

if($variable =~ /^$ENV{HOME}/) {
    $variable =~ s/^$ENV{HOME}//;
    $home_if_exists = $ENV{HOME};
}

$variable =~ s/\//SLASH/g;
$variable = $home_if_exists.$variable;

print Dumper($variable);
```

$VAR1 = '/home/jtymSLASHabcSLASHdefSLASHmng';